# Magento change product details in packing slip printing

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, packing-slip

I need to change the product details of magento packing slip currently they are showing as follows 
[image]

but I need to display as below to reduce the space taken for one product

[image]

Which file should I look for doing this I have looked at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php
```

and

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php
```

but no luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file that is responsible for this task is:

`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment/Packaging.php` for simple product.

`code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Sales/Order/Pdf/Items/Shipment.php` for bundle product.

**For Items Rendering**

`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Shipment/Default.php`

Comment: I have commented all things in Packaging.php file but no change to the packingslip printing

Comment: and my products are configurable products

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: yes thats it app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Shipment/Default.php is the answer thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php, 
replace ATTRNAME as appropriate.:-

`public function draw() {      product=Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’)->loadByAttribute(‘sku’,         $this->getSku($item), array(‘ATTRNAME’)); if ($product) { $lines[0][] 
array(‘text’=>Mage::helper(‘core/string’)->str_split($product->getData(‘ATTRNAME’), 15), ‘feed’ => 305 ); 
}`

Then add this to Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php,
replace ATTR_TITLE as appropriate and OFFSET with the left offset.

`/* Add table head */ … $page->drawText(Mage::helper(‘sales’)->__(‘ATTR_TITLE’), OFFSET, $this->y, ‘UTF-8′); if (!empty($settings[‘table_header’])) 
{
 $page->drawText(Mage::helper(‘sales’)->
(‘ATTR_TITLE’), OFFSET, $this->y,  ‘UTF-8′); 
}`

There is no definitive solution as you need to change a few other details to limit column widths in other areas depending on where you are trying to put your values (ie. description is usually made narrower and forced to line-wrap).

Referenced from: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18142/P15/#t20162

Comment: this is for invoice printing right ? not for packinglip printing